# Protractor and Teamcity with grunt

Tags: selenium, teamcity, gruntjs, protractor

I'm trying to get some protractor tests going on Teamcity with Grunt.

I am uncertain how to set up the runner. I've tried using command line runner, but with no success.

I am able to call protractor with Grunt, but the issue is with 'webdriver-manager start'.

I am able to start the Selenium server but the server does not terminate, so build sits there and TC doesn't know when to start protractor tests...

What is the best approach for setting up Protractor tests with Teamcity? Is it common to let Selenium run all the time on the agent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can write [Ant Script](http://ant.apache.org/) that will run your test, with it can launch different apps, like Selenium server with some parameters.
I use Ant to run my Selenium WebDriver Tests on Team City (URL: http://joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2013/12/09/c35/2e7/c0400edc3ee4e58b13a2fc113112526414dfa211.jpg?v=2.4.0)
[image]

```
  <target name="run-test" failonerror="true">
        <exec executable="dir\file.exe">
            <arg value="-t target"/>
            <arg line="some line" />
        </exec>
  </target>
```

If it returns exit code 0 then your test ran succeful

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrian, my fault, I didn't explain well. We are using Grunt. I've updated my question

Comment: If grunt can take additional arguments and has exit code u can use Ant. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again Andrian, but we don't want to use Ant at all. Just Grunt directly.

Comment: Did u figure this out Thibs?

Comment: Ended up using grunt plugin for team city, works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this now and have something mostly working. Assuming you're using the grunt protractor runner, try removing `seleniumAddress` from your protractor.conf.js file. If it's not supplied, grunt (or protractor or something) will launch it for you and shut it down afterward.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling for hours with this and now I feel like an idiot...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the selenium-Server the you can add the below code in the conf.js 
directConnect:True